# Where should my add-on save its presets .txt file?

Tags: python, scripting

I created a script that saves all my Property Groups in some callable text files, it works fine, for now the path is `path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__ file__), "Preset")`, I can read and overwrite on ".txt" files the data correctly. I now have the permissions on Win10 to access this folder and write. But I don't know very well if it's a correct practice when creating an add-on others will use, especially on other operating systems Mac and Linux. Does anyone know how to handle it correctly? Where should my add-on store this file?

Comment: Is this in the context of creating an add-on that other people might use?

Comment: @Ray Mairlot, yes